# Addition of a number and a vector

Tags: vectors, wolfram-alpha

Does it mathematically make sense for a number to be added to a vector (or matrix for that matter)? When I put $4 + [1, 2, 3]$ into Wolfram Alpha it gives me $[5, 6, 7]$, i.e. the number is added to each item, but this doesn't seem correct to me as I would have thought that the number would just be added to the 1st item of the vector - or is neither correct?

Comment: What does correct mean? Formally, this is addition is not defined.

Comment: Mathematica has other code for string operations, Append$[\{1,2,3\},4]$ gives $\{1,2,3,4\}$ for example.  Or, to your example, Prepend$[\{1,2,3\},4]$ gives $\{4,1,2,3\}$.There is no universally recognized meaning for something like $4+[1,2,3]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally speaking, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{v} = (v_k)_{k=1}^n \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for $n>1$, then $x + \vec{v}$ is not a defined operation, unlike $x\vec{v}$, which is defined to be component-wise multiplication, i.e., $$x\vec{v} := (xv_k)_{k=1}^n.$$

Thus, you can define the addition to be whatever you like to make life easier and notation simpler.

In many computer implementations, e.g. Mathematica or Python's `numpy`, you will find the notation
$$
x + \vec{v} := x \vec{1} + \vec{v} = (x + v_k)_{k=1}^n,
$$
which sometimes serves as a useful notational shorthand.